# Integration test two http requests that depend upon each other in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, testing

I have an async (epoll based) http server written in mix of C and C++ that serves as a message broker and runs on Linux/MacOS. This is the scenario that I am manually testing with `curl` in multiple shell windows that I want to automate.

Request 1: Long poll asking for a message. There are none, so this request waits until a message arrives.

Request 2: Puts in a message that resolves request 1.

I'm unsure of the best way to orchestrate this. Any recommendations would be massively appreciated. My current thought is to use threads for the requests and have the responses write to files, and then a sleep/wake/check file for data loop with some timeout...but I'm hoping that better tooling/approaches exists :)

Comment: @user463035818 I wrote the server in a mix of C and C++. I thought it might be entirely possible to do all of the testing from within a C or C++ testing framework. I don't really care if I use C for the framework or C++ or neither

Comment: ok sorry then, text says "written in C++", so I wrongly assumed you mixed them up accidentally. Question correctly tagged as c and c++ are quite rare ;)

Comment: [thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) seems the solution, but `sleep` not, there are other way to communicate/synchronize between thread as [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)